# Poblar de datos un datatable desde un JSON

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Trabajo con ASP.NET MVC, estoy utilizando la librería [DataTable.net](https://datatables.net/)

Estoy trayendo datos desde la base de datos por medio de un JsonResult que me devuelve la información en un texto plano.

Método

```
// GET: Cliente
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Cliente> _cliente = clienteService.GetAll().ToList();
        config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Cliente, ClienteViewModel>());
        List<ClienteViewModel> list = config.CreateMapper().Map<List<ClienteViewModel>>(_cliente);
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Desde el HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clientes").DataTable({
        paging: true,
        searching: true,
        bProcessing: true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "Cliente/Index",
            "columns": [
                { "data": "ClienteId" },
                { "data": "RazonSocial" },
                { "data": "NumeroDocumento" },
                { "data": "Direccion" },
                { "data": "Fijo" },
                { "data": "Email" },
                { "data": "Estado" }
            ],
            "dataType": "json"
        },
        "language": {
            "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sSearch": "Buscar:",
            "sUrl": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "Primero",
                "sLast": "Último",
                "sNext": "Siguiente",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

El problema es que me muestra una pagina con la siguiente información
[image: JSON]

Creo el tema pasa por dejar el Index como ActionResult y crear un método JsonResult que cargue la table.

Actualizando como tengo mis métodos.
Controller

```
 // GET: Cliente
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult ListaClientes()
    {
        List<Cliente> _cliente = clienteService.GetAll().ToList();
        config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Cliente, ClienteViewModel>());
        List<ClienteViewModel> list = config.CreateMapper().Map<List<ClienteViewModel>>(_cliente);
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clientes").DataTable({
        //paging: true,
        //searching: true,
        //bProcessing: true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "@Url.Action("ListaClientes")",
            "dataSrc": '',
            "type": "GET",
            "columns": [
                { "data": "ClienteId" },
                { "data": "RazonSocial" },
                { "data": "NumeroDocumento" },
                { "data": "Direccion" },
                { "data": "Fijo" },
                { "data": "Email" },
                { "data": "Estado" }
            ],
            //"dataType": "json"
        },
        "language": {
            "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sSearch": "Buscar:",
            "sUrl": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "Primero",
                "sLast": "Último",
                "sNext": "Siguiente",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Error
DataTables warning: table id=clientes - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see

Comment: porque no devuelves un JsonResult en vez de un ActionResult, hasta donde entiendo el ActionResult devuelve una pagina nueva por así decirlo y el JsonResult solo devuelve un Json

Comment: @JuankGlezz También he probado con ActionResult creo debo ser una método ActionResult el cual llamae a un método JsonResult que obtenga los datos y devolver una view.

Comment: solo una duda el controlador index es llamado al cargar la vista previamente o es un método sin pagina?

Comment: @JuankGlezz No pude responderte antes había salido a hacer unos tramites, respondiendo a tu pregunta en el Action Index solo devuelvo una vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi duda es igual a la de JuankGlezz puesto que si tu metodo Index retorna un Json no puedes llamar la vista Index al mismo tiempo. Pero voy a ponerte un ejemplo claro de tu pregunta.

Tenemos el método Index el cual llama a la vista Index que contiene una Tabla(DataTable) donde se muestran los clientes.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

La vista tienen lo siguiente:

```
    @*ESTO YA NO LO NECESITAS YA QUE LOS CLIENTES VIENEN EN UN JSON*@
    @*@model IEnumerable<WebApp1.Models.Cliente>*@

    @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <p>
      @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
<table id="clientes" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Id
            </th>
            <th>
                RazonSocial
            </th>
            <th>
                NumeroDocumento
            </th>
            <th>
                Direccion
            </th>
            <th>
                Fijo
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
            <th>
                Estado
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#clientes").DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    "url": "@Url.Action("ListadoClientes")",
                    "dataSrc": ''
                },
                columns: [
                    { "data": "ClienteId" },
                    { "data": "RazonSocial" },
                    { "data": "NumeroDocumento" },
                    { "data": "Direccion" },
                    { "data": "Fijo" },
                    { "data": "Email" },
                    { "data": "Estado" }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Si te fijas el script quedó mas corto al eliminar parámetros que al final se llaman por defecto, como son `busqueda`, `paginación` y `filtrado`. La parte interesante es donde se difine la opción `url` la cual defino con el Helper `@Url.Action` que trae ASP. Esto por defecto pasa a nuesto controlador como `GET` por eso creo un método el cual retorne un Json con un listado de Clientes. Quedando de esta forma:

```
    public class ClienteController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: /Cliente/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ListadoClientes();
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult ListadoClientes()
        {
            var clientes = db.Clientes.ToList();
            return Json(clientes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        .......
}
```

`JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` TE PERMITE RESPONDER CON JSON A PETICIONES DE TIPO GET, SI NO LO PONES TE DARÍA UN ERROR 500.
Otra parte importante es declarar `"dataSrc": ''` en tu scrip para trabajar con un array Json. De esta forma funciona perfectamente espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Me sale el siguiente error: DataTables warning: table id=clientes - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4, respondiendo a tu pregunta en el Action Index solo muestro una vista.

Comment: Voy a poner mi código de nuevo, voy actualizar mi pregunta.

Comment: Amigo prueba copiar textualmente mi ejemplo que funciona, tanto la vista como el controlador y si tu Index muestra una vista entonces deberias crear otro metodo para retornar la lista de Clientes en formato Json, tal y como te lo he mostrado. Saludos

Comment: He probado tu código y me da el mismo erro, los campos que traigo en mi consulta que son 9 y en el JSON solo necesito 7, esa puede ser la causa del problema?, ¿puedes mostrar una imagen de la carga de datos del datatable.net?

Comment: No salía por que falto llamar al método json desde el action Index, ya lo puse y salió.